# How to use single quote string and double quote single with antlr at the same time?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I encounter a problem in antlr3 that i want to describe single quote string , double quote string and composite quote string. but the code can't be compiled.

```
SingleQuoteString
    :
    '\'' ( ~('\''|'\\') | ('\\' .) )* '\''
    ;

DoubleQuoteString
    :
    '\"' ( ~('\"'|'\\') | ('\\' .) )* '\"'
    ;

StringLiteral
    :
    (SingleQuoteString|DoubleQuoteString)+
    ;
```

The error reported is that SingleQuoteString has a conflict with StringLiteral.

The three kinds of string may be used at the different time.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: @JiriTousek, they have the same prefix, the second present will be not reached.

Comment: Please post the exact message, and also indicate which line it refers to if there's any line information in the exact error message

Answer (score 3):

There really is a conflict between `DoubleQuoteString` and `StringLiteral`, and also between `SingleQuoteString` and `StringLiteral` - `StringLiteral` can match anything a `SingleQuoteString` can match (and more).

Remember we're talking about lexer rules, not parser rules (ANTLR convention says Uppercase first letter means lexer rule). And lexer cannot base it's decision on any context. It has to emit a token. Which token should it emit upon reading `'abc'` for example? Should it emit `SingleQuoteString` or `StringLiteral`? The input matches both, and lexer has no other context.

The way around this is to make `StringLiteral` a parser rule rather than lexer rule.